# Why output of FFT is same as input data size ?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

What I understand from DFT formula below I can decide the N my self. I can try to use just 16 bins to describe a function or I may even use 4 , it won't be very accurate but I can do it right?

[image]

The confusing part is even most thrusted websites say [next sentence taken from this link](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform): The most general case allows for complex numbers at the input and **results in a sequence of equal length** .

That is extremely strange to me because lets say I have 100000 data , and complexity of fourier is Nlog(N), do I have to go with 100000log(100000). Why can't I go with less accurate but more efficient N=16. Why libraries won't implement like this?

Ps: As a computer science graduate I am sorry if my question is not scientific enough but I asked it to stackoverflow, DSP site etc.. but couldn't clear my mind. I hope I made my point this time .

Comment: The DFT is a function from $\mathbb C^N$ to $\mathbb C^N$.  The DFT simply changes basis, to a special basis -- the "discrete Fourier basis".  Each $N$th root of unity $\omega$ gives us one discrete Fourier basis vector $[1,\omega,\omega^2,\ldots,\omega^{N-1}]^T$.  (Normalize it if you'd like.)  You can easily check that the discrete Fourier basis vectors are eigenvectors of the cyclic shift operator $S$:  $S[1,\ldots,\omega^{N-1}]^T = [\omega^{N-1},\omega,1,\ldots,\omega^{N-2}]^T = \frac{1}{\omega}[1,\ldots,\omega^{N-1}]^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use $16$ or $4$ bins, yes. I find it strange that libraries don't implement arbitrary bin counts, but I suppose I would shrug and say it's probably because they're written for people dealing with much more data than you.

(Unless you're just trying to use 16 bins for large data sets for your own amusement, but then you should probably be writing your own DFT functions :P )

Comment: I am so happy somebody finds it strange too thank you so much ,you made me happy , not just people not finding it strange ,when I asking about this it seems nobody understands my point.

Comment: For example if I need to get 16 bins out of 10000 data I should take 16 points and put them in a buffer myself for passing them to library function which cause unnessary memory allocation, but libraries can do that without a new buffer .

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir: To be fair to them, you're not very clear. In particular for this question (as Ross Millikan mentioned) you are maybe unknowingly asking two separate questions here: One about input size, and one about runtime. (My answer is only about input size)

Comment: You are right , thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the length of the sequence of values and the amount of computation to get the Fourier transform.  The definition of the Fourier transform (fast or not) takes $N$ values in time and returns $N$ values in frequency.  If $N$ is a power of $2$, the FFT allows you to do a number of floating point operations that scales as $N \log N$ to get the result.  A naive Fourier transform routine would take $N^2$ operations.  The result will be the same either way.  The FFT is clever in using repeatable sections of the calculation to improve efficiency.  For $N=16, N \log N=64, N^2=256$ only a factor of $4$ different.  But for $N=2^{16}=65,536, N \log N=2^{20}=1,048,576$, while $N^2=2^{32}=4,294,967,296$, or $4,096$ times higher.

Comment: Thanks for answer espically the "takes  N values in time and returns N values in frequency." part I believe libraries should be clever enough to set the bin size. Also thanks for additional advices even I am aware of  difference between DFT and FFT and  I am well aware of the difference between NlogN and N^2.